# Understanding SubscribtionEndpoint and RecieveEndpoint in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to understand MassTransit configuration in conjunction with Azure Service Bus.

At configuration time there're 2 methods with overloads: `SubscriptionEndpoint<T>` and `RecieveEndpoint`. How I understand how messaging with MT and ASB works.

There're 2 kind of messages: events and commands. Events are published via `Publish<T>` method and delivered to a Topic. They can be consumed by many different applications. Commands are sent via `Send<T>` method and delivered to a Queue. Message from queue is consumed only once (e.g. concurrent readers).

So, I thought that SubscribtionEndpoint stands for configuration of events and therefore it has `<T>` for routing via type convention and RecieveEndpoint is used for connecting command sender and command handler.

But my test app say that regardless weather I use SubscribtionEndpoint or RecieveEndpoint, I still can receive events.

Let's consider example:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, queueName: "AnotherSubscirber2", configure: configurator =>
{
    configurator.Handler<ObjectCreatedB>(context =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Another subscirber, object b created");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```

The 2nd parameter has name queueName but is used as subscriber name on topic. When I publish an event using `publishEndpoint.Publish<ObjectCreatedB>`, I'm able to handle this message. 
So MT has crated subscription on the topic:

[image]

How does it know that it needs to listen `ObjectCreatedB`? Queue name was `AnotherSubscirber2` but MT created subscription `AnotherSubscirber2` instead. Is parameter named correctly?

If I add this code, I still accomplish the same:

```
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<ObjectCreatedB>(host, subsriberName, configurator =>
{
    configurator.Consumer<ObjectBCreatedEventHandler>();
});
```

Then, what's the difference? How do I register command handler not event handler then? Or am I missing something? My sample code is [here](https://github.com/elepner/MTExperiments).

Thanks in advance!